# Creating a Dependency-Aware Model Binder in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

The code below tries to create a dependecy-aware model binder. **The model binder should instantiate an object based on the object in the request**. However, I don't see the logic in the code below, which only instantiate on object. Furthermore, I try to debug it, **the CreateModel method is NOT invoked.**

```
Creating a DI-Aware Model Binder


using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace MvcApp.Infrastructure {
public class DIModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) {
return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(modelType) ??
base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
}
}
}
```

This class uses the application-wide dependency resolver to create model objects and falls back to
the base class implementation if required (which uses the System.Activator class to create a model
instance using the default constructor).

We have to register our binder with the application as the default model binder, which we do in the
Appliction_Start method of Global.asax, as shown below.

```
Registering a Default Model Binder



 protected void Application_Start() {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new DIModelBinder();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Comment: What the heck is `Listing 17-31`? Are you copying this out of a textbook?

Comment: Please refer to my rectified update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I defined an attribute-based custom model binder, which takes precedence over DIModelBinder.